# Custom CSS for iPad Mini 2, retina display and @media screen/viewport settings

Tags: html, css, media-queries, viewport, retina-display

I'm trying to specify different colors for selected range of screen sizes, however I just can't seem to figure out the iPad Mini 2 with Retina Display. It does simply not follow the rules of it's pixel resolution and I wonder why.

**Here is my code:**

```
/** Retina iPad **/
@media
screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5){
    body {
        background-color: #486ffd;
    }
}
/** 1600px non-retina screen **/
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px){
    body {
        background-color: #770029;
    }
}
/** 1000px non-retina screen **/
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    body {
        background-color: #117700;
    }
}
/** 500px non-retina screen **/
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    body {
        background-color: #ffce00;
    }
}
/** 300px non-retina screen **/
@media screen and (max-width: 300px){
    body {
        background-color: #770200;
    }
}
```

Now when my iPad Mini 2 is in portrait mode it shows the background color #117700, and when I have it in landscape it shows the color #770029. How come it does not follow the rules of its resolution on: 2048x1536?

I also have this in my HTML:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1; maximum-scale=3;" />
```

I've tried using both a pixel ratio on 1.5 and 2 which has been suggested by others in previous questions. Any help?

The website I am using is [here](http://www.gogetit.no) if you wish to see for yourself.

Comment: Did you try changing the 1600 value just to see where the breakpoint is, and it does what you'd expect ?

Comment: @adeneo The problem is that I dont want to use max-width: 1600px for the retina display, as I wish to have the mobile version on the retina display whenever it is placed in portrait mode. Otherwise all the website elements get so small and the website gets annoying to use on the retina tablet. That is why I am trying to use the pixel ratio instead.

Comment: Any of these help you out: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was solved by putting the CSS specification in the correct order.

> When selectors have an equal specificity value, the latest rule is the
>   one that counts.

I also added:

```
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi)
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx)
```

In order for it to be even more fit and specified.

```
/** 1600px non-retina screen **/
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px){
    body {
        background-color: #770029;
    }
}

/** Retina iPad **/
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx){
    body {
        background-color: #486ffd;
    }
}
```

So correct order is: **LAST** overrules **FIRST**, which means device-width needs to be overruled by the retina specifics. More about this can be read here [CSS Specificity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: And there you go, +1 !

Comment: @adeneo Thank you for your help figuring it out Adeneo, +1! :)