# Handling device-width on a fixed-width website

Tags: html, mobile, mobile-website, device-width

I have a website that has a fixed width of **1024px** and is centered on desktop. On mobile devices, the width should match the size of the phone or tablet.

When using device-width, like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
```

I get following result:

[image: devicewidth]

I get the same result using `width=1024`.

... Which is really confusing, since the user is unable to gather an overview. I don't know why `device-width` sets the website's viewport to this particular size. I would expect otherwise.

What I'm expecting and what I really want is something this:

[image: expectancy]

**Question:** How do I tell the device to fit the website on the screen exactly?

Comment: What you got when remove scale factor from meta tag? And another question: do you want users to zoom (scale) page or not? I shall try better:  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,
                               maximum-scale=1.0" />

Comment: Apparently, this solves the issue. Post it in the answers and I'll accept it :)
By the way, is it possible to also fit the page height, if for instance, the page is far more wide than high?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you got when remove scale factor from meta tag? And another question: do you want users to zoom (scale) page or not? I shall try better:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

and also:

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0" />
```

For fitting height and width you can play with those meta:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="height=device-height, width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes|no" />
```

Comment: That's all the info I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In order to make a website adaptive and responsive I recommand using

```
@media screen and (max-width: the max width you want){ }
```

You can also add this in your . This will make the initial scale 1 and allow for some zooming into 3.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=3" />
```

You also need to use % instead of pixels on wrap elements. This way it adjust according to your screen.

Here is an example:

- For devices with 0-500px width, run the second CSS code.
- For devices with 500-1600px width, run the first CSS code.

**You can also specify for retina using this:**

```
@media
only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx){ }
```

**This is the other example:**

```
/** From 500 - 1600px width **/
@media screen and (max-width: 1600px){
    body {
        background-color: #fff;
    }
}
/** From 0 - 500px width **/
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    body {
        background-color: #000;
    }
}
```

I asked a similar question earlier. You can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29185745/custom-css-for-ipad-mini-2-retina-display-and-media-screen-viewport-settings).

Comment: This is not the way we understand doing programming. I think we should not use hard-coded values. If we think only about iOS devices, this should be a temporary  solution. What about  you have so many devices as per Android?

Comment: @user3344236 You are correct. Using hard-coded values isn't the best. However, I just set the retina screen as lowest. Everything over the given values will run aswell. However you are correct. I should change the values accordingly. A full list can be found here: http://bjango.com/articles/min-device-pixel-ratio/

Comment: dito. I don't want to use responsive layouts for various reasons and hard-coded widths of current devices are not useful in a few years, or even now considering the vast variety of devices.

Comment: @bytecode77 Then I would go with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />` as suggested by others. May I ask why you dont wish to use responsive layouts?

Comment: If you're interested, take a look at my website (http://bytecode77.com) and then you'll discover that the content doesn't qualify for responsive layouts.

Comment: @bytecode77 I can't find anything that dont qualify. Set max-width and you will not have a problem with images :) Nice content by the way! :)